# How to check if an LDAP user is disabled?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to check if an `LDAP use`r is disabled or not, through a `PHP script`.

In my script, I use these 2 following lines:

```
$user_info=$adldap->user()->info($username,array("useraccountcontrol")); <br>
$enabled = (($user_info[0]['useraccountcontrol'][0] & 2) == 0);
```

I have tested the script for an enabled user and for a disabled user but the variable `$enabled` **`returns TRUE`** for both of the users!!

Any ideas? Thanks!!!!!

Comment: I'd say it depends on how your LDAP stores the information that a user is disabled. So more Informations about the used systems might help to find an answer. Are you querying an OPenLDAP or an ActiveDirectory or an OpenDirectory or anything else? Are we talking about SMB-Disabling or LDAP disabling?

Comment: I second that. Difficult to answer without seeing your schema and a little explanation on your code. OpenLDAP for example has no built-in mechanism nor a standard enabled attribute in the built-in schemas. We implemented the enabled feature using a custom attribute isEnabled.